# Auto login Tampermonkey script returning POST 404

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

EDIT (see here *)

I wrote this simple auto login Tampermonkey script for https://app.7mind.de/login

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         7Mind User Login Website
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://app.7mind.de/*
// ==/UserScript== 

let emailAddress = document.getElementsByName('email');
emailAddress[1].value = "x@y"
let password = document.getElementsByName('password');
password[1].value = "pass"
let loginButton = document.getElementsByName('submit');
loginButton[0].click();
```

I am getting this error in the console in Chrome:

```
POST https://api.7mind.de/v1/login 404
```

Grabbing the login button by class also doesn't work - same error.

```
let loginButton = document.getElementsByClassName("_2N3ybblop__YQd82Xe-Uw1");
```

As for the page's behaviour, I don't see my credentials getting inserted on the website.

*Also, when I leave out loginButton[0].click(), the credentials are inserted, but the same error occurs when I then click manually on login.

However, from what I read on the net, such simple login scripts should work.

Is this some recent Chrome security feature blocking my login attempt?

Answer (score 0):

The API is returning 404 for `Incorrect email or password`. Check the Network Tab in Developer Tools of the browser.

Edit: Try this approach [github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135#issuecomment-314441175](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135#issuecomment-314441175) Why? If the app is using a framework like ReactJS, changing the element value through JS doesn't actually update the state of the React component, so the next time the component refreshes, the changed data is gone whereas what is sent to the server is the component's state.

Comment: Thx. Double-checked. The credentials I hardcoded are correct, but indeed does the Network tab show "incorrect email or password". I also printed the values of emailAddress[1] and password[1] after setting and they are correct. Any other idea?

Comment: Try this approach https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135#issuecomment-314441175 Why? If the app is using a framework like ReactJS, changing the element value through JS doesn't actually update the state of the React component, so the next time the component refreshes, the changed data is gone whereas what is sent to the server is the component's state.